# How to encode foreign language characters in response in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Response: {"message":"Un contrÃ´le de routine de votre vÃ©hicule a Ã©tÃ© effectuÃ© ","level":"4"}

I'm using content encoding UTF-8 in HTTP Request and included "file.encoding=UTF-8" in system.properties. But i guess this works on encoding request and not response. It would be great if someone can suggest a solution for this?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

below property needs to be set in jmeter.properties file

sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

In a HTTP Sampler, I just added the Content encoding type as UTF-8 and it worked like a charm for me.

[image: Screenshot]